# How can I change a static method behavior in C++?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking

Is there a way to modify the behavior of a static method to return different parameters?

I am using Gmock for mocking but in this case I am not able to change my code and the methods must stay static

for example

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    static int GetSomething()
    {
        return -1; 
    }
};
```

I need the method to return positive number

Answer (score 2):

In that case your options are limited, but if it's just for a mock, then just make the method return a static variable instead of a hard coded value.

```
class MyClass
{
  static int somethingValue;
public:
  static int GetSomething()
  {
    return somethingValue; 
  }
  static void SetSomething(int value)
  {
    somethingValue = value; 
  }
};
int MyClass::somethingValue = -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer - I work at Typemock the unit-testing company.
You can easily change the behavior of a method with our API, for example:

```
WHEN_CALLED(MyClass::GetSomething()).Return(15);
```

In that way, in all of your tests, `GetSomehting` will return 15.
It will work on Non Static methods too.